# What is the Puiseux series of the Bessel function $J_n(n)$?

Tags: special-functions, laurent-series, bessel-functions

By numerical experimentation I find the first three terms of the [Puiseux series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series) of the Bessel function of the first kind

$$
J_n(n) =
\frac{\Gamma(\frac13)}{2^{2/3}\cdot 3^{1/6} \cdot \pi}n^{-1/3}
- \frac{1}{35\cdot 6^{1/3}\cdot\Gamma(\frac13)}n^{-5/3}
- \frac{\Gamma(\frac13)}{225 \cdot 2^{2/3}\cdot 3^{1/6}\cdot \pi}n^{-7/3}
+\mathcal{O}(n^{-11/3})
$$

How does this series continue?

See also [this application](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/191021/26598).

### How I got this far

#### first term

For the first term, start with the integral representation

$$
J_n(n) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} d\theta \cos[n(\sin(\theta)-\theta)]
$$

For $n\to\infty$ the only significant contributions to this integral come from values of $\theta$ that are close to zero. Therefore we approximate $\sin(\theta)-\theta\approx-\theta^3/6$ and find

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{1/3}\cdot\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} d\theta \cos[-n\theta^3/6] = \frac{\Gamma(\frac13)}{2^{2/3}\cdot3^{1/6}\cdot\pi}
$$

In *Mathematica*:

```
Limit[1/(2π) Integrate[Cos[n (-(θ^3/6))], {θ, -π, π}]*n^(1/3), n -> ∞]
```

> Gamma[1/3]/(2^(2/3) 3^(1/6) π)

#### second term

In *Mathematica*, define the Bessel function and its one-term approximation, as well as their numerical difference evaluated to 1000 digits:

```
b[n_] = BesselJ[n, n];
ba[n_] = Gamma[1/3]/(2^(2/3)*3^(1/6)*π)*n^(-1/3);
B[n_] := N[b[n] - ba[n], 10^3]
```

Calculate how the numerical difference behaves for large $n$ (after multiplying it by $n^{5/3}$):

```
ListLinePlot[T = Table[B[n]*n^(5/3), {n, 10^Range[2, 5, 1/4]}]]
```

and find the approximate numerical value of the limit as $n\to\infty$:

```
NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[T]
```

> -0.00586928848357833870

Then use [AskConstants](http://askconstants.org) to find that this number is probably equal to $-\frac{1}{35\cdot 6^{1/3}\cdot\Gamma(\frac13)}$.

#### third term

Same procedure as second term, but with the better approximation

```
ba[n_] = Gamma[1/3]/(2^(2/3)*3^(1/6)*π)*n^(-1/3) -
           1/(35*6^(1/3)*Gamma[1/3])*n^(-5/3);
```

and multiplying the difference `B[n]` by $n^{7/3}$ before taking the numerical limit $n\to\infty$. The result is $-0.0019880325262065435671$, which [AskConstants](http://askconstants.org) thinks is equal to $- \frac{\Gamma(\frac13)}{225 \cdot 2^{2/3}\cdot 3^{1/6}\cdot \pi}$.

#### higher-order terms

The above recipe can be continued to higher-order terms, but I lose confidence in the capabilities of [AskConstants](http://askconstants.org). The fourth term is $+0.00048679979012516409164$, which may be

$$
+\frac{1213}{511875\cdot6^{1/3}\cdot \Gamma(\frac13)}n^{-11/3}
$$

but such large rationals don't inspire confidence.

Comment: Nitpick: this is not a Laurent series, it's a [Puiseux series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series)

Comment: Thanks @Wojowu, edited & learned something.

Comment: I don't know what has been your process (I really would like to know) but this is beautiful.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici please have a look at my writeup, I'd love to get your feedback.

Comment: I just repeat myself : impressive. Very nice approach. I did not know about this *AskConstants* stuff

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.19.E8)?

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician no I hadn't seen this. Your link proves that my three terms are correct, but does not provide any more terms. I'll have a look at the literature quoted at the bottom of the page for the case $a=0$. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, [Watson](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=Mlk3FrNoEVoC&pg=PA233) indeed has it; the formula is attributed [to](https://doi.org/10.1002/asna.18911272203) [Meissel](https://doi.org/10.1002/asna.18911280802).

Comment: Very good. I'm preparing an answer based on this reference. Thanks for the help, @J.M.isnotamathematician

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician. Thanks for the reference to this paper and for the other stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is given by [Ernst Meissel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Meissel) in [this 1891 paper](https://doi.org/10.1002/asna.18911280802) (in German):

$$
J_n(n) = \frac{1}{\pi}
\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}
\lambda_m \cdot
\Gamma\left(\frac{2m+4}{3}\right)
\cdot \left(\frac{6}{n}\right)^{\frac{2m+1}{3}}
\cdot \cos\left(\frac{2m+1}{6}\pi\right)
$$

The coefficients $\lambda_m$ describe the Taylor series of the solution $u(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \lambda_m x^{2m+1}$ of the transcendental equation $u-\sin(u)=x^3/6$ around $x=0$. Term-by-term comparison gives

$$
\lambda_0=1\\
\lambda_1=\frac{1}{60}\\
\lambda_2=\frac{1}{1400}\\
\lambda_3=\frac{1}{25200}\\
\lambda_4=\frac{43}{17248000}\\
\lambda_5=\frac{1213}{7207200000}\\
\lambda_6=\frac{151439}{12713500800000}\\
\lambda_7=\frac{33227}{38118080000000}\\
\lambda_8=\frac{16542537833}{252957982717440000000}\\
\lambda_9=\frac{887278009}{177399104762880000000}\\
\lambda_{10}=\frac{15233801224559}{39217856135377920000000000}\\
\ldots
$$

These coefficients can be calculated efficiently with the *Mathematica* code

```
λ[0] = 1;
λ[m_Integer /; m >= 1] := λ[m] = Module[{Λ, u, x},
  u = Sum[λ[j] x^(2 j + 1), {j, 0, m - 1}] + Λ x^(2 m + 1);
  Λ /. First[Solve[SeriesCoefficient[u - Sin[u], {x, 0, 2 m + 3}] == 0, Λ]]]
```

Or all at once by series inversion (thanks to J.M.): calculate $\lambda_0\ldots\lambda_n$ with

```
With[{n = 5},
  ComposeSeries[InverseSeries[Series[u-Sin[u], {u,0,2n+3}]], x^3/6 + O[x]^(2n+5)]]
```

> $$
> x+\frac{x^3}{60}+\frac{x^5}{1400}+\frac{x^7}{25200}+\frac{43 x^9}{17248000}+\frac{1213x^{11}}{7207200000}+\mathcal{O}(x^{12})
> $$

Thanks to J.M. who pointed out Meissel's paper to me.

Comment: If you need a whole pile at once: `ComposeSeries[InverseSeries[Series[u - Sin[u], {u, 0, 25}]], x^3/6 + O[x]^25]`

Comment: Thanks @J.M.isnotamathematician , I was wondering how to make `InverseSeries` work on this case.

Comment: Note that this is a divergent asymptotic expansion, you cannot write $=$, use $\sim$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the notation of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1142/S021953051450033X) to the one given in the accepted answer, the coefficients $\lambda_m$ may be computed recursively as follows (cf. Appendix A.$2$). Let $P_0 (x) = 1$ and
$$
P_m (x) =  - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^m {\frac{6}{{(2k + 3)!}}\int_0^x {P_{m - k} (t)\,{\rm d}t} } 
$$
for $m\ge 1$. Then
$$
\lambda _m  = \frac{1}{3}\frac{{( - 1)^m }}{{\Gamma \big( {\frac{{2m + 4}}{3}} \big)}}\int_0^{ + \infty } {t^{\frac{{2m - 2}}{3}} {\rm e}^{ - t} P_m (t)\,{\rm d}t} 
$$
for any $m\ge 0$.